# How do I SSH to a server, get a file from that server, and append it to a file on the original server?

Tags: shell, unix, ssh, server, ksh

So I have a shell script script that runs on two different Unix servers that puts its output into a file on each of the respectable servers. From server A, I'd like to SSH to server B, get the output file and append that to the output file on server A so i only have to read one report. What would some example syntax for that be?

Comment: Have you tried anything for this? Have you noticed that you can run a remote command via ssh directly (instead of spawning a shell)? `ssh user@host remote_command`?

Comment: Yes it is and after researching it that seems like the best way to go. Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: `ssh serverB cat /path/to/output/file >> /local/path/to/serverA/output/file`???

Answer (score 0):

Get the file using scp, then concatenate both files